# NodeJS json web token problema al comprobar el usuario logueado

Tags: nodejs, express, jwt

os explico lo que pretendo:

En un servidor desarrollado **Express** estoy intentando simular las conexiones de logins de usuarios, esta direccion me devuelve un token gracias a **jsonwebtoken** con el que me permite acceder a una url protegida que evita entrar a direcciones no logueadas.

Si entras devuelve un error **Forbidden** y una vez obtengo el token deberia de aparecer  contenido del usuario que se registrar (un simulacion hecha con un objeto hardcodeado) pero me sale lo mismo **Forbidden** 
Una vez dicho todo esto os expongo mi codigo:

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    text: "api works !"
  });
});

app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  const user = { id: 3 };
  const token = jwt.sign({ user }, "my_secret_key");
  res.json({
    token
  });
});

app.get("/api/protected", ensureToken, (req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.token, "my_secret_key", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json({
        text: "protected",
        data
      });
    }
  });
});

//comprueba si esta logeado correctamente el usuario
function ensureToken(req, res, next) {
  const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  console.log(bearerHeader);

  if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    //cogemos lo que nos interesa del array partido
    //ejemplo: name a24sd2a4s3d2as (nos interesa los numeros solo)
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server on PORT 3000");
});
```

**Foto de la peticion postman**

[image: Foto de la peticion postman]

Comment: Muéstranos cómo estás haciendo la petición, déjanos saber de qué forma le envías el token al servidor y así comprender mejor qué está sucediendo

Comment: ¿Cuando realizas la petición estás enviando la cabezera `Authorization: "Bearer ..."` que contiene al token?

Comment: De acuerdo, he actualizado la pregunta y he subido la foto de como lo estoy haciendo. Gracias un saludo

Comment: A proposito de jasonwebtoken , como haria para hacer un logout

Comment: Para realizar un `logout` se puede añadir alguna forma de guardar el estado de la sesión. Siendo que usas *tokens*, mi recomendación es darle un tiempo de expiración a tu token de acuerdo a tus necesidades, aunque eso no es hacer `logout`. Desde el lado del ***backend*** el `logout` tiene varias formas de implementarse. Pero dado que trabajas con *tokens*, es preferible que el `logout` lo maneje el ***frontend***. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, era un problema en torno a que no sabia como hacer correctamente la peticion get pasandole la cabecera y el token generado.

Debia irme al apartado **Authorization** de postman y pasarle el token en el input que me crea el propio postman a la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en el apartado **Authorization** me da la opcion de meter el token del usuario y me devuelve el **response** que esperaba.

Yo lo estaba intentando en el apartado **Body**

Comment: Te recomiendo que complementes más la respuesta, indica cómo estableciste la cabecera usando postman, y además añade que el valor de "Authorization" debe tener la palabra "Bearer" seguida de un espacio y luego el valor del token. Puedes explicar también porqué se usa "Bearer" como valor inicial. Esto es solo una sugerencia. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo. Un saludo.